# How to open pdfs from android device in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Is there any way i could open a pdf without using `Application.OpenURL` or paid plugins because i want to open a pdf inside my `Application.persistentDataPath`.
I could do it with an image but whenever i try with a pdf , it says the file is corrupted and i can not open it in my android device.
Here is the code i used to open a image if it helps:

```
  void LoadImage()
       {
           string filename = "vuzix.png";
           string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);
           LoadContent(path);
       }
    void LoadContent(string path)
        {
            AndroidContentOpenerWrapper.OpenContent(path); //path must be path/to/file.filetype
        }
```

Here is the API i used to implement the script:

https://github.com/Andy-Roger/UnityAndroidNativeFileOpener

**Update:**

I realized this only happens when i try to open a powerpoint converted to pdf file

I tried using a sample pdf file and it worked well

What could be the issue and possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the following plugin i found on github to open the pdf: https://github.com/Mihail5412/Unity-Android-Files-Opener